# Call to undefned function curl_init() в wamp, Что делать?

Tags: curl, wamp

В `php.ini` раскомментировала строку с `curl`, скачала `php_curl.dll` и добавила в папку `win32`. Но не работает.

Comment: `phpinfo();` - ? Подключен? Скорее всего нет, версия `php` какая?

Comment: из мануала: http://www.phpmind.com/blog/2011/02/how-to-enable-curl-in-wamp/

Comment: получается 2 `php.ini` файла надо править.

Comment: сейчас посмотрю. а версия php-3.5.1

Comment: правка двух php.ini не спасла.  а где должен быть подключен phpinfo?

Comment: а рестарт apache был сделан после изменений в конфиге?

php_info это функция. создайте файл `pi.php` и в него напигите `<?php php_info(); ?>` и откройте в браузере его. там будет вся информация о всех моджулях, включенных в вашу версию пхп